# Oracle : Procedure throws Invalid Datatype Error during execution ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, bulkinsert

```
   CREATE TABLE T1 (EMP_NAME VARCHAR2 (40));

    INSERT INTO t1
         VALUES ('Vinoth');

    COMMIT;

    CREATE TABLE T2 (EMP_NAME VARCHAR2 (40));

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG_V
    AS
       PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2);

       TYPE T1_TYPE IS RECORD (EMP_NAME T1.EMP_NAME%TYPE);

       TYPE T1_TBL IS TABLE OF T1_TYPE;
    END TEST_PKG_V;
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG_V
    AS
       PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2)
       IS
          LV_T1_TBL   T1_TBL := T1_TBL ();

          CURSOR T1_CUR
          IS
             (SELECT EMP_NAME FROM t1);

       BEGIN
          OPEN T1_CUR;

          LOOP
             FETCH T1_CUR
                BULK COLLECT INTO LV_T1_TBL
                LIMIT 10000;

             INSERT INTO t2 (EMP_NAME)
                SELECT EMP_NAME FROM TABLE (LV_T1_TBL);

             EXIT WHEN T1_CUR%NOTFOUND;
          END LOOP;

          COMMIT;
       EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS
          THEN
             p_status := 'FAIL';
             RAISE;
       END P_MAIN;
    END TEST_PKG_V;
/
DECLARE
VAR VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
TEST_PKG_V.P_MAIN(VAR);
END;
```

While executing the procedure throws the ORA-00902: invalid datatype.
If I comment out the insert statement inside the procedure, it is running perfectly fine. What is  the problem here and help me with resolution.

Comment: Use: `FORALL indx IN 1 .. LV_T1_TBL.COUNT LOOP  INSERT INSERT INTO t2 (EMP_NAME) VALUES( LV_T1_TBL( indx )); END LOOP;` i place of your insert statement. More on FORALL statement you can find [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to be able to do it like that, the types have to be created outside of your package. Here is the corrected version. Downside is, types beeing created, if you alter your table to change the type of the column, you might forget to modify the type.

```
CREATE TYPE T1_TYPE AS OBJECT ( EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(40));
CREATE TYPE T1_TBL AS TABLE OF T1_TYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG_V
AS
   PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2);
END TEST_PKG_V;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG_V
AS
   PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2)
   IS
      LV_T1_TBL   T1_TBL;

      CURSOR T1_CUR
      IS
         (SELECT T1_TYPE(EMP_NAME) EMP_NAME FROM t1);

   BEGIN
      OPEN T1_CUR;

      LOOP
         FETCH T1_CUR
            BULK COLLECT INTO LV_T1_TBL
            LIMIT 10000;

         INSERT INTO t2 (EMP_NAME)
            SELECT EMP_NAME FROM TABLE (LV_T1_TBL);

         EXIT WHEN T1_CUR%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;

      COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         p_status := 'FAIL';
         RAISE;
   END P_MAIN;
END TEST_PKG_V;
/
```

If you want your types to be generic and adapt to your table, I think you will have to do it something like that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG_V AS

   TYPE T1_TYPE IS RECORD (EMP_NAME T1.EMP_NAME%TYPE);
   TYPE T1_TBL IS TABLE OF T1_TYPE;

   PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2);
   FUNCTION GET_T1 RETURN T1_TBL PIPELINED;

END TEST_PKG_V;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG_V IS

CURSOR T1_CUR IS (SELECT EMP_NAME FROM t1);

FUNCTION GET_T1 RETURN T1_TBL PIPELINED IS
  LV_T1_TBL T1_TBL;
BEGIN
  OPEN T1_CUR;
  FETCH T1_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO LV_T1_TBL;
  CLOSE T1_CUR;
  FOR IDX IN 1..LV_T1_TBL.COUNT LOOP
    PIPE ROW (LV_T1_TBL(IDX));
  END LOOP;
END;

PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t2 (EMP_NAME) SELECT EMP_NAME FROM TABLE (GET_T1);
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_status := 'FAIL';
    RAISE;
END P_MAIN;
END TEST_PKG_V;
/
```

alternatively, you could do it by iterating directly on your cursor :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG_V AS

   TYPE T1_TYPE IS RECORD (EMP_NAME T1.EMP_NAME%TYPE);
   TYPE T1_TBL IS TABLE OF T1_TYPE;
   PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2);

END TEST_PKG_V;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG_V IS

PROCEDURE P_MAIN (p_status OUT VARCHAR2) IS
  CURSOR T1_CUR IS (SELECT EMP_NAME FROM t1);
BEGIN
  FOR CURRENT_ROW IN T1_CUR LOOP
    INSERT INTO t2 (EMP_NAME) VALUES (CURRENT_ROW.EMP_NAME);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_status := 'FAIL';
    RAISE;
END P_MAIN;

END TEST_PKG_V;
/
```